# Adding Sort Keys and Filter to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Oracle that returns a select statement cursor reference.  I want to be able to  pass column names and sort direction (example: 'CompanyName DESC')   and be able to sort the results, or pass a filter such as 'CompanyID > 400' and be able to apply that to the select statement.  what is the best way to accomplish this?  This table is in an old database and has 90 columns, and I don't want to do logic for every possible combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a cursor with an `OPEN-FOR` and `USING`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_table (
    p_sort VARCHAR2
    )
IS
    TYPE cursor_type IS REF_CURSOR;
    cur_out cursor_type;
    lv_cursor_txt VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
    lv_cursor_txt = 'SELECT * FROM table :sort';
    OPEN cur_out FOR lv_cursor_txt USING p_sort;
    -- Opening the cursor isn't probably what you want, but I'm not sure how to associate the variables except on open
    RETURN cur_out;
END;
```

This isn't a very good example, but I hope it helps somewhat.

Oracle talks about this in the [Dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) page.
The DBMS_SQL package may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1288401763279 and http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6711305251199

I especially like this method: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1288401763279#4988761718663

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2177728&tstart=0

CASE WHEN :P4_SORT_ORDER = 1 THEN
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(ENAME))

or decode(:Sort_var,1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(ENAME)),2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(Address)))

Answer (score 0):

As you probably figured out, R. Bemrose's answer is the simpler to implement, using a dynamic SQL.  For that reason, it's probably used the most often.  If you do this, be sure to do it the way he(/she?) did, using a bind variable (e.g. USING p_sort) rather than just concatenating the string onto the lv_cursor_txt.  This method gives better performance and security than concatenating.

The second method uses application contexts, which I haven't seen used much, but I suspect would provide better query performance if you're calling the query a lot.

Good luck.

Comment: Thx.  I assumed as much but didn't want to publicly!  :-)